# Convert Windows 7 system to Qemu with virt-p2v, booting broken

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have a Windows 7 system running on an AMD laptop that I would like to convert to a VM in Qemu under Linux. On booting into Windows, the image produces a BSOD with the standard 0x7B error. I understand this is a disk controller image, probably because the Windows install doesn't have the right disk driver enabled (the laptop has an AMD chipset).

I have tried using virt-p2v (from a RHEL ISO containing 1.36.1), but the error persists.

My qemu command line is:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2G -boot menu=on -cpu host -machine q35 -enable-kvm -vga cirrus -drive file=/path/to/sda,format=raw
```

What can I look at to get this working?

Comment: Run Startup Repair from a Windows 7 installation ISO in the VM. Don't use manually constructed qemu command lines; use libvirt/virt-manager/other virt- tools.

Comment: The original machine had a system partition. I have run Startup Repair from both the system partition and from a Windows-created repair image, and neither resolve any problems. In both cases they report that an unspecified startup error occurred and that it cannot be repaired.